# Simple Permission Set Assignmenent to Contacts

Tags: community, contact, permission-sets

I'm creating a community for our customers who will be in our system as accounts/contacts. I want to add them to the community by adding the community to a permission set, and then assigning the permission set to all current and new accounts we get.

I can find information on how to assign permission sets to users (internal Salesforce users), but not our customers/contacts.

Any advice or resources would be appreciated.

---

**Update**

I tried to reset the password of my newly created user but I got the following error:
[image: Change Password Error]

I'm guessing I incorrectly assigned the user to a community or I didn't at all. I had assumed that after getting a password in their email, they could login to the community that I created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the Customers as Community Users you would not normally need to use a permission set as you have to have profiles created for the community users and assign that profile to the Community.  It is possible if you have multiple communities to use a permission set rather than the community user profile, but if you only want to have a single community it is easier to do it from the profiles.

[image]

Then the users need to be created from the Contact records, this can be done manually from the individual contact records. Once enabled these users can be added to a permission set for their profile type as normal, e.g. Customer Community or Customer Community Plus.

To enable a community user from the Contact select Manage External user and then enable customer user. This takes you to the user creation page where you can enter their details, as per the next two pictures.

[image]

The role is not available on community user licences and is defaulted in on the customer community plus licences. The Profile has to be for the specific licence type and needs to be included in the community profiles. Once these users have been created then it is possible to assign them to a permission set but that may not be necessary as explained previously.

[image]

See also Salesforce documentation on [provisioning communities users](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/06/how-to-provision-salesforce-communities-users.html).

Comment: Thank you. This line in the link you provided is tripping me up. _Create a user record from the contact and assign a user profile that has access to your communities_. In my mind, users are internal employees that have a salesforce license. Here though, it makes it sound like an account holds a contact (or multiple), and a contact holds a _user_. That right there is misleading for me. Is there a difference between community users and employee users that have licenses?

Comment: Customers do have accounts on Salesforce but they are not full Salesforce licences they would be one of the community specific licence types, e.g. Customer Community, while employee users would normally be on Salesforce licences.

Comment: Could you elaborate on _Then the users need to be created from the Contact records, this can be done manually from the individual contact records._ This is exactly what I'm trying to do; map contacts to users in community cloud.

Comment: I've edited in how this is done, the users are not created individually but directly from the User management screens.

Comment: Your help is seriously appreciated. I did all the required steps. Is there a way to manually send the newly activated contact/user login credentials for the community portal login?

Comment: The newly created user should automatically be emailed their credentials from Salesforce. If you reset their password it will send them a new email with the link to the password reset page and then let them enter.

Comment: Hm haven't seen the email yet. Also, I'm looking for the section to reset their password in the User Detail page (where I was able to assign them Custom Community Plus User License). Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: Yes, password reset works the same as a standard user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48087/discussion-between-qarthandso-and-dave-humm).